# Google map not working on entire site wordpress

Tags: wordpress, google-maps

I have never face such issue, however I have made several website live from development server. The issue is I am working on development server and the maps works fine. But I need to shift the site to live and the Google map stopped working.

[image: Screenshot of error]

it shows some error like above screenshot. I have tried to add API key as well. But not sure if I am doing it in correct way.

Edited------
I am using wordpress plugin to show map.

Please help me to fix this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you displaying the Google map? Direct coding (php) or using a plugin? If coding, it could be a php version difference issue (between dev and live). If using a plugin, try deleting it from live and then re-installing.

Comment: How are you transferring (migrating) the working site from dev to live?

Comment: @OpenSourceTrainingRajkot I am using plugin inorder to display map.
For migrating I just download the database and move the files directly. Everythings works fine except Google map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since 22. June 2016 you must provide an API-Key.**

[Get an API-Key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key?)

**Your API-Key goes here**:

`<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY" async defer></script>`

[Simple Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple?hl=de)

---

> As of June 22, 2016 we are making the following changes to the Google Maps APIs Standard Plan:
>   We no longer support keyless access (any request that doesn't include an API key). Future product updates are only available for requests made with an API key. API keys allow us to contact developers when required and help us identify misbehaving implementations.

[Source](https://googlegeodevelopers.blogspot.de/2016/06/building-for-scale-updates-to-google.html)

Comment: >> The issue is I am working on development server and the maps works fine. << .. so, it is not likely to be an API-Key issue.

Comment: It is, because the development probably started before API-Key must provided (June or July).

Comment: Yes we started development before June. and I am using wordpress plugin to display map. Should I just copy that URL and add it to header.php updating the api key ?

Comment: This will probably end in an error, because you load the Google Maps API twice. The best solution is simple to add `?key=YOUR_API_KEY`. Maybe there is an update available for this plugin where you can set the API-Key. Which plugin you are using? - Okay it works for you, your welcome :)